# How do I make floating text? ((1.13))

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How does one put floating text like that of servers that utilize plugins to do so? I know you used to be able to do it with earlier than 1.13 with

```
/summon ArmorStand{Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b,CustomName:{"text":"Blocks","color":"yellow","bold",:"true"}} ~ ~ ~
```

but with the 1.13 update they changed the syntax of this and other commands.

Originally, I tried to "fix it", despite not having ran it, by moving the NBT tags to `armor_stand` (since `ArmorStand` didn't exist anymore), but that failed. When I brought it back to the beginning and it summon the object without the custom name either being visible or without having a custom name at all. Which one of those is the issue, however, I'm not sure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error: coordinates go in between the entity name and the nbt.

Second error: the Custom Name needs quotations enveloping the brackets with the name data.

Third mistake: Each quotation within the said brackets must have a backslash before it. Plus, there was a typo in front of "bold" in the command sample you gave us.

A working command:

```
summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b,CustomName:"{\"text\":\"Blocks\",\"color\":\"yellow\",\"bold\":\"true\"}"}
```

Comment: Oh, I dislike those pesky backslashes. Thank you very much! Once the two minute mark hits, I'll mark best answer.

Comment: @EarthToAccess Actually, you cannot express text components in NBT without escaping double quotes, since the text component is stored in a string.